# JsViews vs Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, templating, jsrender, jsviews

I intend to use JsRender for my single page application and I am considering if I should use JsViews or Knockout. JsViews has not reached beta yet but what will be the main difference between these two in terms of speed and functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You already hit the biggest difference ... right now JsViews is not yet at beta. If you need to move forward on data binding now, I would use Knockout.

Comment: the CodeCamper website is using `koExternalTemplateEngine` instead of `jsRender`. Many of us became familiar with `jsRender` and love it because of your course on PluralSight. But why did you avoid `jsRender` in CodeCamper? Does that knockout engine has special advantage over `jsRender`?

Comment: Since I was already using Knockout and it has templating, I chose to use it in Code Camper. If I just needed templating (and realyl fast templating) then I would choose JsRender.